# I am unable to run my spark program in EMR cluster because of org.apache.spark.SparkException

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a spark streaming  fat jar file which I have validated locally

```
spark-submit \
--class Structured.RTP \
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 \
/target/scala-2.11/Structured_Streaming-assembly-0.1.jar \
dev
```

I am now trying to run this in the EMR cluster

[image]

However the program fails [image]

This is the full error form the logs

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-154T9SBGE3IV6/%5C
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$1.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:915)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:915)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:937)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

Comment: exatrct the jar file and look for `public static main` method in `Structured.RTP` class. Also RTP class should be public

Comment: `%5C` is ascii for ``\``. I don't think they are needed in spark-submit options.

Comment: @QuickSilver The class and the method is public

Comment: @mazaneicha %5c is not a part of spark-submit command

Comment: okay, so what are ``\`` doing in "Spark-submit options" on your screenshot?

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes, it was the \ character that was messing up the submission to EMR. I was duplicating exactly what I do in the terminal. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: try to run it by SSH into the master node after managing to run the command add it as a step using command-runner.jar